# How do i discard or revert RStudio's git commit?

Tags: github, rstudio, git-commit

I have created a project on github and integrated it with my RStudio.
By mistake, I have committed a large file from my computer and now I want to revert back or discard that commit.

Can someone help me how I can do it via RStudio.

Thanks..!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo the last commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git reset --soft HEAD^` to remove the commit itself but keep the changes you've made. You can use `git reset --soft HEAD^2` to do this for the last two commits. Then you can make a new commit.

Comment: Of course you have to do this in the Terminal of R Studio by typing in these commands.